# How to assign value of AngularJS variable to PHP variable

Tags: php, angularjs

After storing the value in PHP variable and trying to apply the condition check
but I'm not able to do so.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">      
<?php
    $index= '{{$index}}';
    var_dump($index);

    if ($index==="1" || $index=="1") {
        echo $index;
        # code...
    }
?>
</div>
```

Do you have a solution?

Comment: PHP executes before Angularjs

Comment: this is not the proper angular-php code.

Comment: Can you please help me out how should i write it @AnilKumarRam

Comment: @Drone sir you mean to say i cant do this in this way.
But sir when i do var_dump($index) i am getting the value in the $index variable, but when i do if statement it gives me falls all the time it doesnt checks the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to understand below code..

**db.php**

```
<?php

include '../includes/config.php';

switch ($_GET['action']) {
    case 'add_product' :
        add_product();
        break;

    case 'get_product' :
        get_product();
        break;
}
function get_product() {
    $qry = mysql_query('SELECT * from product');
    $data = array();
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($qry)) {
        $data[] = array(
            "ng_id" => $rows['ID'],
            "ng_name" => $rows['Name'],
            "ng_desc" => $rows['Detail'],
            "ng_price" => $rows['Price'],
            "ng_quantity" => $rows['Quantity']
        );
    }
    print_r(json_encode($data));
    return json_encode($data);
}
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('store', ["ngRoute"]);
app.controller("mainController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.get_product = function () {
        $http.get("db.php?action=get_product").success(function (data) {

            $scope.myData = data;
        }).error(function () {
            $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
        });
    };
}
```

**index.php**

```
//if you want to use bootstrap div structure
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in myData">
      <div class="col-md-4">{{x.ng_id}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{x.ng_name}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{x.ng_desc}}</div>
    </div>

//if you want to use table structure
    <table>
    <tbody data-ng-init="get_product();">
                   <tr data-ng-repeat="x in myData ">
                      <td>{{$index}}</td>
                      <td>{{ x.ng_name}}</td>
                      <td>{{ x.ng_desc}}</td>
                      <td>{{ x.ng_price}}</td>
                      <td>{{ x.ng_quantity}}</td>
                      <td>
                         <a href="" data-ng-click="edit_product(x.ng_id)">Edit</a> | 
                         <a href="" data-ng-click="delete_product(x.ng_id)" modal-backdrop="static">Delete</a>
                      </td>
                   </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Sir i got the code which you have written.
But my question isn't solved using this.

Actually i want to do something like 
<div class="row">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
   <div>6</div>
</div>

So because of this i need to have the index value saves in my php index variable so that i can iterate it as i expect it to do. So in my question i have tried if statement.

Comment: <div class="row" data-ng-repeat="x in myData "><div class="col-md-2">{{x.ng_name}}</div></div>

Comment: sir i want only 3 columns in one row and then next row should begain.

Comment: see the above code... made changes based on div structure... ab samjha bhai :-)

Comment: ill try and do revert. Thanks for your help.

Comment: <div class="row" ng-repeat="x in myData">
      <div class="col-md-4">{{x.ng_id}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{x.ng_name}}</div>
      <div class="col-md-4">{{x.ng_desc}}</div>
    </div>

my case i need 

<div class="row" ng-repeat="x in myData">
      <div class="col-md-4">{{x.ng_id}}</div>
    </div>// this div shouldn't close until the count on iteration id 3.

So because of this i took it in my php variable so that i can iterate as i need.

Comment: Can you share your response data ?

Comment: <div id="colour-picker"><div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index">  
                                <div class="col-md-4 no-spacing">
                                    <div ng-class="($index>='3') ? 'colour more' : 'colour'" data-hint="@{{item.name}}" ng-click="colorSelect(this)" style="background: @{{item.name}}" name=" @{{item.name}}">&nbsp;</div></div></div></div></div></div>

Something like this i want to do but after 3 col there should be a new row rather then everything in one row

Comment: I found the solution

<div id="colour-picker"><div class="container"><div class="row" ><div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index"><div class="col-md-4"><div ng-class="($index>='3') ? 'colour ' : 'colour'" data-hint="@{{item.name}}" ng-click="colorSelect(this)" style="background: @{{item.name}}; height: 100px; width: 250px; margin: 10px;" name=" @{{item.name}}">&nbsp;</div></div></div ng-if="($index+1)%4==0"><div class="row" ng-if="($index+1)%4==0"></div ng-if="($index)%4==0"></div></div></div>